# convert a whisper-small.pt model to hugging face through convert_openai_to_hf.py

Tags: pytorch, huggingface, python-3.11, whisper, config.json

I have a problem I want to convert a file with the extension .pt to CTranslate2 and to do that you first need to convert it to hugging face and then execute a commande line that will convert the file whisper-small.pt into faster whisper small.I try to execute this commande it gives me error I don't really know which commande to execute I try this commande line

> python3 src/transformers/models/whisper/convert_openai_to_hf.py --checkpoint_path "whisper-small.pt" --pytorch_dump_folder_path "openai/whisper-small" --convert_prepro.

I want the model whisper-small.pt to be convert in to hugging face through a commande line I have already installe all the dependences necessary